# How to do this effect in ActionScript 2.0?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

Hey guys, i have this example: http://www.fakedc.com/exemple/exemple.html

how i can make this in AS2.0???

i dont want the art, only programming, put your mouse over the circles and you will see the effect I want to do

Comment: Without filters very difficult, more art than programming.

Comment: i dont want the art, only programming, put your mouse over the circles and you will see the effect I want to do

Comment: Sticking to AS2 is a bad idea, unless you have a VERY good reason (laziness is not an option). And BTW it has nothing to do with filters (you could use a set of pngs for instance) :)

Comment: i dont know AS3.0, only as2.0, and the site where I will implement it, was developed in AS2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to look at using a repulsion algorithm. The basic idea is that as you move the mouse, elements are measured to determine their linear distance to the mouse and then moved along the same angle away from the mouse. You can find an AS2 example in this forum post:

http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=72396

Comment: very nice... Rudi... this is the basic idea. in this example, the movieclip dont back to your original place...but.. is this!.. ty very much...